# How to Call Pagemethod in Angular js Service

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

i am new in Angular js.

Static Method in Code Behind

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetPracticeLocations()
{
     return "[{ id: 1, name: Test AccountName}]";        
}
```

Angular JS Service

```
appSettings.service('PracticeLocationsService', function () {
     this.getPracticeLocations = function () {
          var PracticeLocationsData = PageMethods.GetPracticeLocations();
          return PracticeLocationsData;
     };
});
```

i want to know how to implement page method in Angular `JS`.

Any helpful suggustein apricited

Thanks

Comment: Fyi, your json is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Probably I'm too late, but you could use defer to call a page method and return a promise,

```
var getPracticeLocations = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        PageMethods.GetPracticeLocations(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                deferred.resolve({ result: angular.fromJson(response) });
            } else {
                deferred.resolve({ result: null });
            }
        },
                function (msg, code) {
                    deferred.reject(msg);
                });
        return deferred.promise;
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at [`factory()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) and [`$http`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

pseudo code:

```
angular.factory("PageMethods", ["$http", function($http){

    return {
         GetPracticeLocations : function(){
             return $http.get("/someurl");
         }
    }

}]);
```